# Best way to handle multiple assetlinks.json URLs for Multisite?

Tags: multisite, server, filesystem

When running PWA/TWA apps built on WordPress, they require an `assetlinks.json` file to be served from the root domain of each site. I'm wondering if anyone has come up with a solution to this using WordPress Multisite?

The only option that comes to mind is a virtual file sort of like these plugins create:

- [Virtual Robots.txt](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pc-robotstxt/)
- [Ads.txt Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ads-txt/)

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056006/how-to-create-assetlinks-json-when-website-is-handled-by-multiple-apps